# Event Hub Producer with Websockets through API Gateway

Tags: azure, proxy, azure-eventhub

Can anyone advise what connection parameters are needed in an EH Producer client when using a Proxy.

I am actually using a API Gateway with AMQP Support (CA Layer7) with an outbound proxy.

Does the connection string for "String Endpoint" need to be my Proxy target  or the Event Hub connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string would not change; the `Endpoint` token should still point to the Event Hubs endpoint.   To use a proxy, you'll need to set the configuration with the options used to construct the producer.   You don't mention the specific language that you're using, so I'll illustrate with the .NET SDK.   The general form would look something like:

```cs
var connectionString = "<< CONNECTION STRING FOR THE EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE >>";
var eventHubName = "<< NAME OF THE EVENT HUB >>";

var producerOptions = new EventHubProducerClientOptions();
producerOptions.ConnectionOptions.TransportType = EventHubsTransportType.AmqpWebSockets;
producerOptions.ConnectionOptions.Proxy = new WebProxy("https://proxyserver:80", true);

var producer = new EventHubProducerClient(
    connectionString,
    eventHubName,
    producerOptions);
```

More discussion and examples can be found in repository samples [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample02_EventHubsClients.md#setting-a-custom-proxy).